# Deleting a photo in the camera roll

Tags: iphone

Can I delete a photo in the camera roll? If so, how can I do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to delete a photo from camera roll?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16846344/how-to-delete-a-photo-from-camera-roll)

Comment: Be warned, the answer to this is out of date (it's possible since iOS 8). The moderator deleted my answer and told me to mark it as a dupe instead (even though that requires 3000 points). There is a way to do this, but apparently if I tell you, my post will be deleted.

Answer (score 2):

No, and I would be very afraid if there was.

Comment: Why be so afraid? iPhone's native photo app can delete photo, why not allow other apps delete photo which selected by user( UIImagePickerController)?

Comment: Using a `UIImagePickerController` would be okay, but I wouldn't be happy as a user if there were an API to directly delete pictures from the Camera Roll.

Comment: Buggy API programming by a developer could wipe out a user's camera roll? no thanks. I agree, a UIImagePickerController would be useful, but not direct access.

Answer (score 0):

This is now possible in iOS8+ using the [`deleteAssets`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Photos/Reference/PHAssetChangeRequest_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/PHAssetChangeRequest/deleteAssets:) method of the [`PHChangeRequest`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Photos/Reference/PHAssetChangeRequest_Class) object.

iOS will prompt the user for permission when you call this method.