# How to delete a photo from camera roll?

Tags: ios, photolibrary

I can write photos to camera roll, but how can I delete one?

I remember a couple years ago someone said it is impossible, but I believe I have seen an app recently that did it.

Answer (score 3):

To delete photo from camera roll is not possible from application. Apple has never given access of delete photo of camera roll from application.

Answer (score 3):

This is now possible (since iOS 8). Hopefully this helps other folks who end up here from Google.

To do this, check out the `deleteAssets` method of the `PHAssetChangeRequest` class.

Docs here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Photos/Reference/PHAssetChangeRequest_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/PHAssetChangeRequest/deleteAssets:

Comment: Interesting. Skimmed through the docs but couldn't find the part where the system asks for permission from the user before deleting items. I assume it **must** happen at some point.

Comment: @NicolasMiari it prompts the user when you call that. It tells them how many photos you are deleting and lets them confirm/deny.

Answer (score 1):

I could be wrong but I do not think you can delete photos that were not created or stored by your app. AT least I have not seen an Apple API to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You can try 百度魔拍 it really can delete photo from camera roll. (https://itunes.apple.com/cn/app/bai-du-mo-pai/id655426839?mt=8)